# Estrutura de projeto

Tags: java, estilo-de-codificação, deploy, organização-de-projeto

Estou com um projeto sendo desenvolvido com `VRaptor` e tenho uma dúvida sobre estrutura de
projeto.

O projeto que estou desenvolvendo será instalado em vários clientes,
cada um com uma estrutura diferente.

1. Não sei como será a configuração do JPA no cliente, e, como
   haverá vários clientes, cada um com uma configuração distinta, como
   posso fazer para o cliente configurar isto corretamente? Deixo isto
   para o cliente configurar? Pensei em utilizar um datasource ja
   definido no `persistence.xml`, mas se o cliente quer fazer o *deploy* de
   duas instancias no mesmo servidor, como ficaria? Ou há alguma maneira
   de, ao fazer o *re-deploy*, não sobrescrever o arquivo de configuração do
   JPA?
2. Arquivo com algumas definições, isto também é por cliente e varia
   muito de ambiente para ambiente: Há alguma maneira de ler o arquivo
   mas no *re-deploy* não sobrescrever o mesmo (mantendo as configurações
   pré-existentes)? Lembrando que neste caso, dependendo do aplicativo,
   não terá acesso a base de dados para utilizar a configuração do JPA.

Sei que existem *environments* para tratar diferentes configurações,
mas tem muitas informações que não terei do cliente (principalmente
nome do banco e senhas) e não gostaria de ter que criar um `.WAR`
especifico para cada um dos clientes já com suas configurações
definidas.

Em `PHP` consigo tratar a
sobrescrita de arquivos. Neste caso talvez haja outra
maneira de tratar estas dúvidas, estou aberto a
sugestões.

Gostaria de uma solução o mais prática possível, podendo ser usada em qualquer *container*  (`Jetty`, `WildFly`, `Tomcat`, etc.).

Comment: Para resolver o segundo item, eu costumo distribuir um arquivo ***config.properties.modelo*** com as configurações padrão (não incluo no pacote nenhum *config.properties*). Então, na instalação o cliente remove o *.modelo* do nome do arquvio e customiza seu conteúdo; e durante a atualização o arquivo do cliente nunca será substituído pois o arquivo substituído será apenas o arquivo modelo.

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao SOPT! Removi as saudações e agradecimentos de sua pergunta(http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/851/3907) e tornei ela mais objetiva. Por favor leia esta pergunta do Meta para entender melhor porque fiz isso.

Answer (score 3):

Quanto à **primeira dúvida**, o padrão da arquitetura Java EE é que a aplicação declare no `web.xml` de quais DataSources ela depende e a configuração seja realizada no servidor de aplicação no momento do deploy pelo cliente ou responsável.

Para os casos onde o cliente pode querer duas instâncias da aplicação apontando para diferentes DataSources, cabe a ele configurar corretamente o servidor.

Infelizmente, cada servidor de aplicação tem sua configuração própria. Por exemplo, no Tomcat cria-se um arquivo `context.xml` para cada aplicação com os respectivos DataSources. Já no Websphere e Weblogic é possível vincular as dependências de recursos aos DataSources através do painel administrativo.

Por outro lado, é bem possível ignorar os DataSources do container e deixá-los a carga da aplicação. Uma forma bem simples é carregar o `persistence.xml` a partir de um diretório ao instanciar manualmente o `EntityManagerFactory`. A configuração desse diretório poderia ser feita por variável de ambiente, então o cliente ainda teria a flexibilidade de apontar para qualquer diretório. Sendo possível definir variáveis específicas para cada JVM ou para cada aplicação (em alguns servidores, pelo menos), ainda seria possível ter diferentes arquivos de configuração para cada instância da aplicação.

Dados como usuário e senha são sempre responsabilidade do cliente, sua aplicação nunca deve carregar esses dados dentro do pacote.

Quanto a sua **segunda dúvida**, configurações dependentes de ambiente devem ser armazenadas em algum local do ambiente.

A grande maioria das aplicações corporativas armazena as configurações ou "parâmetros" de sistema em banco de dados. Isso facilita o gerenciamento por parte do cliente, afinal somente é necessário conhecer um pouco de SQL para fazer a manutenção quando necessário.

Outra forma comum é armazenar as configurações em arquivos XML, Json ou properties (este último mais comum por ser um padrão da plataforma Java). Não recomendo apontar diretamente para um diretório, mas usar a mesma técnica descrita logo acima, isto é, utilizar uma variável de ambiente. A variável de ambiente pode ser definida em vários níveis: sistema operacional, usuário do SO, JVM, Servidor de Aplicação ou para uma única aplicação.

Em todo caso, um item muito importante é ter um roteiro para instalação inicial e atualização do sistema.

Também é importante fazer uma espécie de homologação da aplicação nos diversos servidores de aplicação. Infelizmente há diferenças enormes entre eles e nem sempre a compatibilidade é tão fácil de ser atingida. Alguns servidores JEE vêm com um caminhão de bibliotecas que podem conflitar com o que tem sua aplicação, cada um tem uma forma de resolver esses conflitos.

---

### Atualização

#### Configurações específicas no Tomcat

No Tomcat, o `context.xml` é o arquivo de configuração ideal para apontar para *Data Sources*, principalmente no que se refere a bancos de dados. Basta usar a tag `<Resource>`, conforme a [documentação](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#Database_Connection_Pool_(DBCP)_Configurations).

Você também pode usar o arquivo *context* para definir parâmetros de contexto ou variáveis de ambiente específicas da aplicação. Veja a [documentação](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Context_Parameters).

#### Configurações específicas no JBoss

No JBoss você pode configurar os *Data Sources* no arquivo `standalone.xml`, que fica num subdiretório do servidor.

Existem outros arquivos para configurações específicos da aplicação, veja a [documentação aqui](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Deployment+Descriptors+used+In+WildFly).

Esses arquivos de configuração ficam dentro do WAR e, assim como o arquivo `context.xml` do Tomcat, são chamados de ***deployment descriptors***, pois são arquivos que configuram o *deploy* da aplicação num servidor específico. Cada servidor deve ter o seu, com mais ou menos flexibilidade.

#### Como carregar um arquivo específico por aplicação

Você também pode carregar um arquivo de configuração externo diferente para cada aplicação ou instância da aplicação da seguinte forma:

1. Defina uma variável de ambiente apontando para um diretório de configuração, por exemplo: `/path/to/conf`.
2. Crie um `ServletContextListener` para carregar a configuração durante o *startup* do sistema.
3. Leia a configuração usando o diretório configurado, mais o *context path* como nome da arquivo.

Dessa forma se houver duas instâncias da mesma aplicação em diferentes contextos, por exemplo `/myappinstance1` e `/myappinstance2`, cada uma acessará sua própria configuração, respectivamente:

- `/path/to/conf/myappinstance1.properties`
- `/path/to/conf/myappinstance2.properties`

Comment: Entendi. Mas no caso, teria algum exemplo de como apontar e ler um arquivo de configuração por context, pode ser no WildFly, Tomcat ou Jetty?

Comment: @Walkovyr Havia lhe respodido em comentários, mas devido ao tamanho acabei apagando-os e coloquei como atualização na minha resposta.