# Arquivo de configuração

Tags: java, spring, log4j

Tenho uma aplicação `web (war)` legada onde várias configurações de ambiente estão dispostas em arquivos XML, ex.: o caminho do BD está no `context.xml`

```
<Context path="/Base"   reloadable="true" crossContext="true">
    <Resource name="jdbc/infodata" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
     maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" username="xxxx" 
     password="xxxx"driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"                
     url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;instanceName=SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=db" />
</Context>
```

Para gerar o `WAR` da aplicação de acordo com o ambiente do cliente uso o `Jenkins` com o Plugin do `Ant`, configuro um `JOB` para cada ambiente diferente.

E uso um `script` do `Ant` para carregar as `configs` de cada ambiente e escrever em todos `XML's` de configuração da aplicação.

Isto envolve `context`, `config` do `log4j` e `configs` de serviços do `spring`.

Os problemas disso, são que fico com inúmeros arquivos `war` iguais, apenas com as `variaveis` de ambiente diferentes, e as versões sistema ficam "zicadas". Enquanto `cliente X` está na  **versão 56**, `cliente Y` está na **2** mas são idênticas, por exemplo.

Existe algum modo que não seja "gambi" que eu possa em tempo de execução ler um arquivo de configuração externo ao `war` e fazer a configuração do `context.xml`, `log4j.xml` e `spring-services.xml` ou melhorar este processo de alguma forma?

Comment: Pergunta relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45978/227

Answer (score 0):

O problema é a falta de uma apropriada separação entre o código da aplicação e a configuração.

Você não deveria saber os dados de conexão (senha!) dos clientes. É justamente para isso que servidores de aplicação Java fornecem um *data source* que a aplicação consome.

Uma forma comum é que cada cliente possua um Tomcat (ou qualquer servidor de aplicação) com as devidas configurações específicas e o WAR distribuído seja igual para todos. Quando a aplicação inicializa, ela lê as configurações que estão em cada cliente.

As aplicações geralmente possuem um conjunto de configurações padrão para *logging* e *flags* do sistema. Configurações específicas podem ser feitas pelo suporte ou pelo próprio cliente se houver pessoal habilitado ou uma ferramenta de configuração.

Claro que tudo depende do modelo que usado para distribuir sua aplicação, mas o importante é ter a configuração específica de cada cliente separada dela. Pense na configuração como um segundo banco de dados.

Os únicos casos onde é possível ou desejável ter a configuração junto com a aplicação são para fins de testes locais ou automatizados, por exemplo, num servidor de integração contínua como o Jenkins.